# Can we think of grothendieck topologies (in ZFC + $U$)?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

(Here a set means an element of a universe $U$.)

We can define a cite as an ordered pair ($C$, $T$) which is that $C$ is the category and $T$ is a grothendieck topology. Usually, we define a category and a grothendieck topology as a set, so is a cite. However, I don't know cite***s*** is a set. That is because for me it is unclear that grothendieck topolog***ies*** that can be given to a category is a set(as is well known, a collection of sets is not always a set.) Can we think of grothendieck topologies?

Comment: What is a "cite"? Did you mean "site"? In general, if $X$ is a set, then a topology is an element of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$. So the collection of all topologies on $X$ is certainly a set, assuming that $X$ is a set as well.

Comment: @AsafKaragila A Grothendieck topology is not quite the same as a topology, but a similar argument applies (see my answer).

Comment: @Mark: Well, close enough.

Comment: I made a spelling error, sorry. As you said, I should have wrote "site".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Asaf mentions in the comments, you mean *site* not *cite*.

Let us fix some small category $\mathcal{C}$. Then a Grothendieck topology consists for each object $X$ of a collection of *sieves* on $X$. A sieve is a collection of arrows into $X$. Of course, all of these need to satisfy certain axioms, but that is irrelevant for determining whether or not things are small (i.e. sets).

Since $\mathcal{C}$ is small $\operatorname{Hom}(A, X)$ is a set for all objects $A$ and $X$. So the collection of all arrows into $X$,
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(-, X) = \bigcup_{A \in \mathcal{C}} \operatorname{Hom}(A, X),
$$
is a set because there is only a set of objects in $\mathcal{C}$. So a sieve on $X$ is just some element of the powerset $\mathcal{P}(\operatorname{Hom}(-, X))$, which is a set. The Grothendieck topology has for every $X$ a collection of sieves on $X$, which is just an element of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\operatorname{Hom}(-, X)))$. We need such a collection of sieves for every object $X$, so a Grothendieck topology is an element of
$$
G = \prod_{X \in \mathcal{C}} \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\operatorname{Hom}(-, X))),
$$
which is again a set. Not every element in this set will be a Grothendieck topology (we included way too many things). So we can take
$$
G' = \{ g \in G : g \text{ is a Grothendieck topology on } \mathcal{C} \}.
$$
Then $G'$ is the collection of all Grothendieck topologies on $\mathcal{C}$ and by construction $G'$ is a set.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I understand the proof that grothendieck topologies are always a set.